# Error on page refresh in MVC 4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have created a webform in MVC 4.. it's working properly but if i wish to refresh a page in between form fill procedure then it'll generate an error :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'orderID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult OrderEdit(Int32)' in
>   'NorthwindWebApplication.Controllers.OrdersController'.
>
> An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary
>   contains a null entry for parameter 'orderID' of non-nullable type
>   'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   OrderEdit(Int32)' in
>   'NorthwindWebApplication.Controllers.OrdersController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter.
>
> Parameter name: parameters Source Error: An unhandled exception was
>   generated during the execution of the current web request. Information
>   regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified
>   using the exception stack trace below.

Now , how to deal with it??? It's just about usual testing.. If i wish to refresh then in that order i must be able to see current form again with blank text boxes instead of an error page.

Comment: Seems you sent null value to the post method **OrderEdit**, which you have to send "orderID" (integer). Could you debug the orderID value in OrderEdit method?

Comment: Trying setting a default value to the input parameter. Something like ActionResult OrderEdit(int orderId = 0);

Comment: Guys , I just want my application to redirect back to the same page instead of throwing an error page on refresh.. so , how should i handle this error in my code.. I have tried with TRY-CATCH block but it's also not working.. such error also occur when i refresh output page..

Comment: Add a null check to the input parameter and if it is null then simply return the same View. eg: return View(new YOURVIEWMODEL());